# Newton's Method: finding more than one root?

Tags: polynomials, roots, newton-raphson

I'm reading Wiki's page on [Netwon's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for root finding.  I understand more than one root can be found, however unsure how it is accomplished.  For instance, if the polynomial is degree $n$ it will have $n$ roots.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

$$
x_{0A} = a, x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
$$

I recall reading something about repeating the process from $x_{0B} = x - a / 2$, however unsure what the variables in this are.

Comment: Why do you believe you should use a numerical method to find repeated roots.  Why not use the [polynomial GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) with its derivative?

Comment: Newton's' method still works for multiple roots. It's just slow.

Comment: @EricTowers I was considering polynomial regression and wanted to determine the number n of roots of a function, so I can form a regression model of polynomial degree n

Comment: @MarkSaving how does it work after finding the first root within some error?

Comment: @Nick You mean using the method to find more than one root, not using it to find a single multiple root. I was confused about this. A "multiple root" of a polynomial is a root $r$ such that $(x - r)^2$ is a factor of the polynomial. I assume you did not intend to refer to this definition.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'm interested in finding all the zero crossings of the function

Comment: It is unclear what your starting point is.  Do you actually have a polynomial's exact coefficients and you are trying to find its roots, or (based on comments) do you have (potentially noisy) samples from some function you would like to model as polynomial and are trying to estimate the number and location(s) of the model polynomial's root(s)?

Comment: @EricTowers There exists $f(x)$, that I would like to solve for $x$ in $f'(x) = 0$.  This should give me the degree $n$ of the polynomial to fit to the function.  Then solve for $p(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0, p(x_i) = y_i$.  Specifically following this step: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#Constructing_the_interpolation_polynomial

Comment: It is still very unclear what you are after, but if your intent is to approximate $f(x)$ with a polynomial to estimate its value at other locations, your current approach will almost certainly give you disastrous results. That [nice picture the Wikipedia page shows?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation#/media/File:Interpolation_example_polynomial.svg) Tweak those points just a tiny bit up or down and instead of that nice 3rd degree, you'll get a 7th degree polynomial that swings wildly between the points. Use a cubic spline for interpolating values, you'll be much happier.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I tried Newton's method for finding more than one value of $x$ which $f(x) = 0$, yet Newton's method seems to converge at only a single value when I know there are more.  How do I find all x values where the function is zero?  I looked at cubic splines, but was also considering interpolating by determining the count of $x$ where $f(x) = 0$ and placing multiple polynomials of this degree into a matrix with $x,y$ values and solving for the coefficients in $g$.  $Ag = B$

Comment: When there are multiple roots, which one Newton's method converges to depends on where you start. Based on the shape of $f$, each root has a "domain" where the method is attracted to that root instead of others. If you can graph $f$, then it is usually easy to figure out where values will converge to each root - but if you have a graph, finding the roots is pretty obvious anyway. One trick you can use is if $a$ is the first root found, next time search for a root of $\frac {f(x)}{x-a}$. It has the same roots except for $a$ (assuming $a$ is a simple root).

Comment: @PaulSinclair The second root is $x_{b_0} = \frac {f(x)} {x - a}$, however $f(x)$ is close to $0$ therefore $\frac {0}{x - a} = 0$.  You would be starting again from zero for every root.  Is that the correct equation?

Comment: Since $f$ is differentiable and $f(a) = 0$, $$\frac {f(x)}{x-a} = \frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \to f'(a)$$ as $x \to 0$. Thus $a$ is only a root of $\frac {f(x)}{x-a}$ if $f'(a) = 0$ (i.e., $a$ is multiple root of $f$). If $f$ is analytic at each of its roots, whenever Newton's method turns up a root $r$, you can replace your current $f$ with $\frac {f(x)}{x-r}$ and keep applying the method to this new function to find another root. If the same root keeps turning up, you keep dividing by it and eventually it will not show up anymore.

Comment: Concerning my original comment: It doesn't matter what method you use to find the minimal degree polynomial through a set of support points. That minimal polynomial will be a horrible choice for interpolation between the points unless you are very lucky. If interpolation is what you are after, use a different method than the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @PaulSinclair do you mean lim $x - a \rightarrow 0$?  Also, $x_{0A} = a, x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{g(x_n)}{g'(x_n)}$ I assume $g(x) = f(x)$, then if first root found is $a$, $g(a) = 0$, then $g(x) = \frac {f(x)} {x-a}$, I assume some something must be added to $x$ or it will resulting divide by $0$.

Comment: (1) $a$ is the root you find. You cannot start with it because you don't know what it is yet. (2) $\lim x - a \to 0$ is a mismash of notations, so I have no idea what you think it means. (3) yes, the first time you do this $g_1(x) = f(x)$. Then once you've found $a, g_2(x) = \frac {g_1(x)}{x-a} = \frac {f(x)}{x-a}$. Once you've found a root $b$ of $g_2$, then $g_3 =  \frac {g_2(x)}{x-b} =  \frac {f(x)}{(x-a)(x - b)}$, etc. (4) Your assumption contradicts what I've already explicitly explained. It is a $\frac 00$ limit and is in fact $f'(a)$. You know what a derivative is, so you can verify it.

Comment: @EricTowers re: Polynomial GCD with derivative.  I read some of the Wiki page and it requires two polynomials.  Do you know how this approach finds the roots?  Thanks

Comment: A polynomial and its derivative are two polynomials.

Comment: @EricTowers so I calculate $A = GCDP(f(x), f'(x))$, now I need to find the roots of $A$.  Is this accomplished algebraically?

Answer (score 1):

Since this does provide one answer to your question (there are others), I'll make it official and walk you through an example. Suppose I want to find the roots of $f(x) = \sin x$ but somehow have no real idea how this function behaves. I calculate the recursion formula $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{\sin x_n}{\cos x_n}=x_n - \tan x_n$$
I arbitrarily choose $x_0 = 1$ and start calculating
$$\begin{array}{rl}x_0&\phantom{-}1\\x_1&-0.557407724654902\\x_2&\phantom{-}0.065936451924841\\x_3&-0.000095721919325\\x_4&\phantom{-}0.000000000000293\\x_5&\phantom{-}0\end{array}$$
(With perfect computing $x_5$ would not be zero. But in this special case, computing error has paid off with a direct hit.)

In general, after finding a root $r_0$, to get the next root, replace $f(x)$ with $f_1(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x-r_0}$. Then $$f_1'(x) = \frac{f'(x)(x - r_0) - f(x)}{(x - r_0)^2}$$
And the recursion formula becomes
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f_1(x_n)}{f_1'(x_n)} = x_n - \dfrac {(x_n - r_0)f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)(x_n - r_0) - f(x_n)}$$

For my example, $r_0 = 0$, so $f_1(x) = \frac {\sin x}x$. This isn't defined at $0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}x = 1$, so if we needed to, we could define $f_1(0) = 1$. But there really isn't a point. We've already found $0$ and are looking for a different root. Why would we want to put the root we've already found back in? It might turn up as a point in the recursion, but this is so unlikely I wouldn't bother with it.

So I calculate the new recursion formula:
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac {x_n\sin x_n}{x_n\cos x_n - \sin x_n} = x_n - \dfrac {1}{\cot x_n - \frac 1{x_n}}$$
And arbitrarily start off with $x_0 = 1$ again:
$$\begin{array}{rl}x_0&1\\x_1&3.79401891249195
\\x_2&2.83731861081935\\x_3&3.12005206105673\\x_4&3.14144824538471\\x_5&3.14159264695285\\x_6&3.14159265358979
\end{array}$$
An interesting alternative approach is to just do one or two iterations of the new formula, then switch back to the original $x_{n+1} = x_n - \tan x_n$:
$$\begin{array}{rl}x_0&1\\x_1&3.79401891249195
\\\hline x_2&3.14205845439180\\x_3&3.14159265355610\\x_4&3.14159265358979
\end{array}$$

Why does this work? Remember that $f_1$ is just $f$ modified to remove the first root. The roots of $f_1$ are also roots of $f$, and with the exception of that first root, the roots of $f$ are roots of $f_1$. The problem is that my starting value of $1$ happens to be in a region where the original formula converges to the root $0$. Different starting values may converge to other roots, but I have no idea what values to try. For well-behaved functions, Newton's method should move me towards a root. So using the 2nd formula for a single iteration moves me from $1$ to $\sim 3.794$, which is close enough to another root for the original iteration to converge to $\pi$ instead of $0$.

Comment: Where $x - r_0$ is in the denominator, will this result in $x = r_0, r_0 - r_0 = 0$ divide by zero? When finding the first root $r_0$ what value is chosen next for x?

Comment: Wow. You just don't listen. Even when I demonstrate it for you, showing you that this notion of yours is both false, and pointless (because you have no reason to stick $x = r_0$ back into the second iteration), you still don't pay attention and insist on sticking with your erroneous assumption. When searching for *any* of the roots, you just make a guess for the starting value. Newton's method will improve on your guess. (Hopefully - Newton's method actually has no guarantee of working. It is extremely rare that it fails, but it can.)

Comment: My question was regarding what value to use for x after finding the first root. The first root obviously cannot be reused as it will cause divide by zero. It seems you suggest that x be another guess and that $x \ne r_0$ holds. Is this correct?